# C++ OpenGL Game Timer

Tags: c++, timer

I am attempting to make a simple game using C++ and OpenGL and I haven't been able to find any good tutorials on creating a simple tick or a timer system for a game i also would like to use an little external librarys as possible.
Any help is appreciated. I am using Win32 and C::B IDE...MingW complier.

Comment: Code::Blocks isn't a compiler btw., its an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this pages:

http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Timers#How_to_use_them.3F

http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

Maybe you can get more answers on [Gamedev Stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ahhh thanks for your help...the last to links will be invaluable

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
void glutTimerFunc( unsigned int msecs, void (*func)(int value), value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`boost::date_time`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want it ultra-precise.

**Edit:** I think the docs are pretty sufficient, you get the count of timer ticks and the timer's frequency. But anyway, here's an example:

*Not tested, but should give you the idea.*

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  LARGE_INTEGER freq;
  LARGE_INTEGER start;
  LARGE_INTEGER current;
  double t;

  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq); // initialize frequency
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&start); // initialize start time

  while (!terminated) // game main loop
  {
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&current); // get current time
    t = (end.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / (double)freq.QuadPart; // transform to seconds

    /* do stuff here with t */
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You could also use any 64-bit integer type instead of `LARGE_INTEGER`, but this is how they intended it.

Comment: great thanks for the example i will have to look into these functions more